# How to use Masonry mas_makeConstraints to avoid conflicts?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, masonry

```
[self.line mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(_line.superview).multipliedBy(0.5);
    }];

[self.line mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(_line.superview).multipliedBy(1.66666);
    }];

    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x14efa7170 UIView:0x14ef3f5a0.centerY == UIView:0x14ef3ec00.centerY * 0.5>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x15026dcb0 UIView:0x14ef3f5a0.centerY == UIView:0x14ef3ec00.centerY * 1.66666>"
```

When I try to update the constraints, there will be a conflict, how to use it correctly?

It looks like the update operation has created a new constraint instead of changing its value.

Can't it be applied in mas_updateConstraints?

Do I have to use mas_remakeConstraints?

Comment: what is the conflict description?

Comment: It looks like the update operation has created a new constraint instead of changing its value.

Comment: I think your code is no problem based on what Masonry says.And I look into the Masonry issue, `however, you cannot alter the multiplier ( NSLayoutConstraint does not allow it ) so you need to use mas_remakeConstraints to update it.` said by the author robertjpayne

Answer (score 1):

Apple doc says:

> Unlike the other properties, the constant may be modified after constraint creation.  Setting the constant on an existing constraint performs much better than removing the constraint and adding a new one that's just like the old but for having a new constant.

Let's paste some vanilla constraints below:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:superview
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:padding.top]
```

According to the [doc](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry#2-mas_updateconstraints), `mas_updateConstraints` is supposed to change the **constant** value of an existing constraint, however, multiplier is **not** the constant part.

Use `mas_remakeConstraints` instead, according to the [doc](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry#3-mas_remakeconstraints), which remove all the existing ones before installing new ones.